# phpExcel VLOOKUP not working with multiple sheets

Tags: php, phpexcel, vlookup

I am feeling stupid today, so forgive me. PphExcel 1.8 and Php 5.5

I am using a VLOOKUP...

When I write it out and load the file in excel everything is good, but when I try and get the resolved value in phpExcel... in variably I get 0... which is the wrong result.
Not sure, but maybe it is because it is on a different sheet

the formula I am using is

```
=IFERROR(VLOOKUP(V3,zLOOKUPS!A2:B3,2,FALSE),zLOOKUPS!B1)
```

The value in V3 is a string and the result coming back from the lookup should be a numeric... I think it is returning 0 because that is what is in the B1 cell... but surely it should not be error-ing in the first place.

Driving me a little bit nuts.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you set the formula, but not the value, Excel assumes the value is good as it is and loads the file without recalculating to save time.  It will not even recalc if you press F9. Only if you 'touch' the cell in Excel will it recalc.

The solution is to tell Excel that formulas have not been pre-calculated by setting the PHPExcel writer object's setPreCalculateFormulas to false:

```
    $objWriter = PHPExcel_IOFactory::createWriter($this->_workbook, 'Excel2007');
    if ($this->_hasCharts) $objWriter->setIncludeCharts(TRUE);
    $objWriter->setPreCalculateFormulas(FALSE);
    $objWriter->save('php://output');
```

Alternatively, you must set both the formula **and** value of each cell. That requires you to calculate the value of the cells of course in PHP.

Note: this is not what happens when you load the file in Libre Office, it  recalculates anyway, either because it ignores the setting or because it is clever enough to realize it need calculating.